# Undefined method split for rollbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This comes up suddenly, I have not observed this for a while, when I tried to run `rake db:migrate` And following the server log. Can anyone help me this 
rake aborted!
```

````
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rollbar-2.7.1/lib/rollbar/rake.rb:23:in `patch?'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rollbar-2.7.1/lib/rollbar/rake.rb:6:in `patch!'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rollbar-2.7.1/lib/rollbar/rake.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rollbar-2.7.1/lib/rollbar.rb:790:in `require_hooks'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rollbar-2.7.1/lib/rollbar.rb:755:in `configure'
/home/gvpmahesh/code/shij/core/config/initializers/rollbar.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/gvpmahesh/code/shij/core/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```
````

Is this the problem with the rollbar gem? Where I am going wrong in this.

Comment: can someone mention me what is wrong with this question, before downvoting.

Comment: I did not downvote, but you might want to go read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not understand, why you guys need to be hard on me. This is not like the starting of the application, this application I am developing for 2 months, I have db setup and all done. I mentioned that out of no where it came up. please understand that rake -v, rake db:migrate did not work at the same time means , there is some system level change :(

Comment: Don't get too beat down, you show some reasoning, and I think you are correct, it is with rollbar. I guess showing some things that you've eliminated would have helped.. like explicitly stating no new migrations added, or what system changes could have happenned, or why you don't know when system changes mights have happenned.. etc..

Comment: hey @gates don't listen to 'those' people. your question is fine, and I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be:

https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/issues/396

You need to check versions. It looks like an update of rake caused a issue when it moved from versions 10. to 11.

"Update: Just noted that the rake gem is updated today (10.5.0 to 11.0.1). In this release the constant RAKEVERSION is removed. See Rake's Github. So a workaround is to hardlock rake on '10.5.0'"

Later on in the thread, they seem to have a fix and you should update to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me, turns out I needed to update the rollbar gem:

```
bundle update rollbar
rake rollbar:test
```